# HTML form one question per page (Ionic 5 / Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

How could I create an HTML form containing one question per screen / page. The user would click "next page" and navigate through the questions. At the end, the user would have the "submit button" and the answer.

Could I open a form < form > element, route through other pages, and close < / form > in another page?

I plan to build something like this using Ionic 5 Angular.

Would anyone have an example?

Comment: definetly all the elements will be inside the form. Its just UI matters. You have to just create a UI with next and previous button for navigating. And this is just happen  in the single page. At a time one section will appear and when you click next, that section will hide and other section will show and lastly on form submit the form will be submit

Comment: As @Developer said. You can also use swiper in Ionic if you want to go for such UX so that user can actually see moving to next/previous question instead of quick rerendering/repopulating of the data in existing form.

Comment: @Developer , ok. Thus I could use < div > and show / hidden css display property.

Comment: @MishaMashina Good idea use swiper. Does Form Element supports Swiper? First should I use < form > and after < swiper > ?

Comment: Yes you can simply hide that part using css display property, when user click next or previous button. And show the next Section of the form. So, it will remain in the single page.

Comment: You can also add animations etc.

Comment: @ALLAN ABU you can put anything into swiper as content, so swiper becomes a wrapper. Take note though: even if you'r on Ionic 5 you should definitely go with swiper,js and not ion-slider, since ion-slider is now obsolete and won't be supported from Ionic 7 onwards.